# Drag and Drop in Aurelia not working

Tags: drag-and-drop, ecmascript-6, aurelia

I am trying to create a drag and drop control for Aurelia. Initially, it works just fine.

```
<div class="card" draggable="true" repeat.for="card of player2.hand">
```

However, when I delegate a listener to the `dragstart` event, the drag no longer works.

```
<div class="card" draggable="true" dragstart.delegate="$parent.dragstart()" repeat.for="card of player2.hand">
```

I can get the dragstart event to fire and the event has `defaultPrevented: true`, which keeps the default drag event from starting. How can I disable `preventDefault` on a particular event delegator in Aurelia?

Comment: I've written an updated and more advanced solution here: http://davismj.me/blog/aurelia-drag-and-drop/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This enhancement has been [added](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/pull/25). To disable `defaultPrevented`, return true from your event handler:

```
function dragStart() {
    // do stuff
    return true;
}
```

In this particular case, you need to return true to enable the default drag behavior.